# change td bgcolor based on result returned

Tags: php, mysql

I found numerous answers but none seemed to work for me.  I have written the following code and I know it picks up the correct color but the td cell for the whole table is set to the color of the first number returned. I need it to reflect the different numbers that might be returned. I have tried to set the value of $backcolor="" at the end of every row iteration but I just cant seem to find the right place to do that ( or if its even possible). Here is what I have written

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    // $backcolor1="" ;

    if ($row["riskPostProbRate"]== '1')    { $backcolor1="green"; }
    elseif ($row["riskPostProbRate"]== '2'){ $backcolor1="green"; } 
    elseif ($row["riskPostProbRate"]== '3'){ $backcolor1="yellow"; } 
    elseif ($row["riskPostProbRate"]== '4'){ $backcolor1="orange"; } 
    elseif ($row["riskPostProbRate"]== '5'){ $backcolor1="red"; }

    echo '<tr class="$altrowcolor"><td>' . $row["riskId"]. '</td><td>'
         . $row["riskName"] . '</td><td >' . $row["riskDesc"] . '</td><td>'
         . $row["riskArea"] . '</td><td>' . $row["riskHeadline"] . '</td><td>'
         . $row["riskPreConCons"]. '</td><td bgcolor=>' . $row["riskPreConProb"] . '</td><td>'
         . $row["riskPreRate"]. '</td><td>' . $row["riskPreLevel"] . '</td><td>'
         . $row["riskRACPrevCons"] . '</td><td>' . $row["riskRACMitaCons"].'</td><td>'
         . $row["riskPostConsRate"] . '</td><td bgcolor=$backcolor1>'
         . $row["riskPostProbRate"] .'</td><td bgcolor=>' . $row["riskPostRate"]. '</td><td>'
         . $row["riskPostLevel"]. '</td><td></td></tr>'; 
}
```

Comment: use <td style="background-color:'.$backcolor1.'"> like this insted of bgcolor property

Comment: provide me what you getting in $result->fetch_assoc()

Comment: @adrian  Check my answer. Or you can use different approach.

Comment: the answer that Sanoj Sharma gave worked.  I simply had to change to  
td style="background-color:'.$backcolor1.' and it worked a charm.  How can I give him/her credit for a correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this  : use proper way : How to set background color to td.

Replace your bgcolor with below code :

**Modified :**

style=background-color: $backcolor1

Comment: I swapped it out and get this :arse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: do one thing : Give me array what you getting in this : $result->fetch_assoc(); I will give you exact answer.

Comment: this is the page that the query returns  http://hama.com.au/mi6/displayra.php is that what you are after.  Thats using my old code not  your new one.

Comment: you are doing right, In you code you just need to replace bgcolor from this : style="background-color:green"

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $backcolor1 = "";

        if ($row["riskPostProbRate"] == '1') {
            $backcolor1 = "green";
        } elseif ($row["riskPostProbRate"] == '2') {
            $backcolor1 = "green";
        } elseif ($row["riskPostProbRate"] == '3') {
            $backcolor1 = "yellow";
        } elseif ($row["riskPostProbRate"] == '4') {
            $backcolor1 = "orange";
        } elseif ($row["riskPostProbRate"] == '5') {
            $backcolor1 = "red";
        }
        ?>
        <tr class="<?= $altrowcolor ?>">
            <td><?= $row["riskId"]; ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskName"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskDesc"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskArea"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskHeadline"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskPreConCons"] ?></td>
            <td bgcolor=""><?= $row["riskPreConProb"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskPreRate"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskPreLevel"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskRACPrevCons"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskRACMitaCons"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskPostConsRate"] ?></td>
            <td bgcolor="<?= $backcolor1 ?>"><?= $row["riskPostProbRate"] ?></td>
            <td bgcolor=""><?= $row["riskPostRate"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row["riskPostLevel"] ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it in php i suggest to create a class in css for each color, than set the class of color you need.

example css

```
.red{
background-color:red;
}
.green{
background-color:green;
}
```

php

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   // $backcolor1="" ;

   if ($row["riskPostProbRate"]== '1'  ){
      $backcolor1="green";
   }elseif($row["riskPostProbRate"]== '2'  ){ 
      $backcolor1="green";
   }elseif ($row["riskPostProbRate"]== '5'  ){ 
      $backcolor1="red";
   }

 echo '<tr class="$altrowcolor"><td class="'.$backcolor1.'">' . $row["riskId"]. '</td><td>' .     $row["riskName"]. '</td></tr>'; 
}
```

i put the class in that td beacuse the row is to long but you can insert the class wherever you want

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following example. this example for change the color in odd even rows

```
$i=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$i++;
$bgcolor=($i%2==0)?'green':'yellow';
echo '<tr bgcolor="<?php echo $bgcolor;?>"><td></td></tr>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Monty's answer, and to make it more understandable as to why the change from single to double quotes, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/906428) which explains thoroughly the effect of using single or double quotes.